# FBX and BVH problems

Tags: animation, three.js

My character is not rendered correctly. It is stretched and animates incorrectly.
I am using the version 93 of three on windows chrome.
Loading the model with out animating is fine.

This is basically what I am doing:

```
let loader: any = new (<any>THREE).BVHLoader();
loader.load("scenes/test3d_caveman/graphics/29-5/cavemanCharaacter_BVH/cavemanCharaacter/01_01.bvh", (result) => {
    var boneContainer2 = new THREE.Group();
    this.obj.add(boneContainer2);
    boneContainer2.add(result.skeleton.bones[0]);
    boneContainer2.add(this._fbxObj);

    (<any>this._fbxObj).skeleton = result.skeleton;

    // locate SkinnedMesh and bind skeleton
    this.obj.traverse((child) => {
        if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh) {
            let skinnedMesh: THREE.SkinnedMesh = <THREE.SkinnedMesh>child;
            skinnedMesh.bind(result.skeleton);
        }
    });

    let mixer: THREE.AnimationMixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this._fbxObj);
    this._mixers.push(mixer);
    mixer.clipAction(result.clip).setEffectiveWeight(1.0).play();
});
```

Anybody have some suggestions why it is not working?

Peter

Comment: Impossible to help you without seeing the working example. Could be your exporter, could be the skinning, could be your code... upload a working example on jsfiddle.net so people can actually see what the problem is.

Comment: Sharing one or the other of the models would also help; where does FBX come into play here?

Comment: yeah. I understand the point about the example. it was a general description of what I am doing. I have create a self contained example. you can download it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hEKu9mQzjPhUg4J0Hf4PolVVs4BOKtDg/view?usp=sharing